# Suppose $f(z)$ is real-valued for all $|z| = 1$. Show that $f(z)$ is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $\{|z| < 1\}$ and continuous on  $\{|z| \leq 1\}$. Suppose  $f(z)$ is real-valued for all  $|z| = 1$. Show that $f(z)$ is a constant

---

Consider  $g(z)=e^{if(z)}$, then $\underset{z\in \overline{D}(0,1)}{\text{max}}|g(z)|=\underset{z\in \partial D(0,1)}{\text{max}}|g(z)|=\underset{|z|=1}{\text{max}}|e^{if(z)}|=|e^{(Ref+iImf)}|=1$ since $Imf=0$

Now because $\forall z\in D(0,1)\:|g(z)|=e^{-Imf}$,  $|g|$ takes maximum iff $Imf=0$,
from the related post, I know that somehow I can show $Imf=0,\: \forall z\in D(0,1)$, then by maximum modulus $g$ is constant, and because $f$ analutic and $D(0,1)$ connected $\Rightarrow f $ is constant

But I don't see how. Can someone show this ?

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036294/fz-is-analytic-on-z-leq-1-and-fz-is-real-on-z-1-sh)

Comment: Why doesn't the related linked question solve the problem? especially @GReyes reply?

Comment: @Gribouillis what is the uniqueness for the Dirichlet problem, I don't know it, i google it, but I still didn't understand it, can you state the theorem and how it's used here ?

Comment: The Dirichlet problem is $-\Delta u = 0$ in the disk and $u=\phi$ on the boundary. There is a unique solution, for example when $\phi$ is continuous on the circle. In particular, if $\phi=0$ then $u=0$. In @GReyes reply, this is applied to $u  = \Im(f)$.

Comment: I think you mean $$\max_{|z|=1} |e^{i f(z)}| = \max_{|z|=1} |e^{i \mathrm{Re} f(z) - \mathrm{Im} f(z)}| = 1$$

Comment: The image of the unit circle is a compact subset of the reals, so is a closed interval, but the complement of that is connected and that is impossible since the image of the open unit disc is open, bounded and connected with boundary included in that interval

Comment: @Conrad If $|\Im(f(z))|$ is maximum at $z_0$, this contradicts the open mapping theorem at $z_0$ (unless $f$ is a constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is not constant, by the open mapping theorem, $f(D)$ is open, where $D$ is the open unit disk. In particular there are points $z\in D$ where $\Im(f(z)) \not = 0$. Now $z \mapsto |\Im(f(z))|$ is continuous on the compact set $\overline  D$, hence there is a point
$z_0\in\overline D$ where $|\Im(f(z))|$ is maximal. We have $z_0\in D$ because $f(z_0)\not \in {\mathbb R}$. Hence $f(D)$ is a neighborhood of $f(z_0)$, but this contradicts the maximality of $|\Im(f(z_0))|$.

This is a contradiction, hence $f$ must be constant.